# Семантически правильные теги HTML для карточки товара

Tags: html5, разметка, семантика

Прохожу обучение, где:

1. для разметки карточки товара рекомендуют использовать тег `<article>`;
2. для разметки кнопок вроде "избранное" рекомендуют использовать тег ссылки `<a>` (хотя переход на другую страницу не предполагается, разве что js на сайте вообще не будет использоваться - этим, кстати, и объясняют использование ссылки, а не кнопки, "на всякий случай".

Пример кода карточки:

```html
<article class="card">
  <h4 class="card-title">
    <a class="card-link" href="#">
      Amara Resort & Spa
    </a>
  </h4>
  <img class="card-img" src="" alt="">
  <p class="card-description">
    <span class="card-description-title">Гостиница</span>
    <span class="card-description-defenition">От 4000 ₽</span>
  </p>
  <a class="button" href="#">Подробнее</a>
  <a class="button" href="#">В избранное</a>
  <p class="star star-four">
    <span class="visually-hidden">4 звезды</span>
  </p>
  <p class="card-rate">Рейтинг: 8,5</p>
</article>
```

Я вижу, что у других сайтов используется другая разметка - `<div>` для карточки товара, для кнопки "избранное" - `<button>`. Какие теги всё же следует использовать, как это принято делать в реальной работе? И вообще, может зря я уделяю этому такое внимание?

Answer (score 1):

Если существуют теги, роль которых определена, то лучше использовать их. я читала, что поисковые движки ориентируются на семантические теги и правильно примененные семантические теги добавляют вес странице в поисковой выдаче. Помимо этого, семантические теги помогают программе-ридеру лучше ориентироваться на странице (речь об озвучке для слабовидящих). К примеру, навигация по странице для слабовидящих происходит с помощью заголовков <h[1-6]>.  Думаю, использование семантических тегов обусловлено не только этим.

Comment: Спасибо! Я разделяю это мнение (особенно как бывший сеошник :)). Я возможно неправильно изложила вопрос, а именно - я не понимала, почему для карточки товара использовался тег <article> (тем более что другие сайты так не делают, а неуместное использование тегов также мб чревато), т.к. он предназначается для "законченных элементов контента,  которые могут свободно распространяться и повторное использовать". Вот это "свободно распространяться" меня смущало, но я уже разобралась)